# What is the time between groups of events when single events have a Poisson distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I'll ask this with a concrete example to be clear.

Let's say I have a Poisson process that tends to produce one event every two minutes. Then the probability of getting an event in a given minute is about 30%, and the probability of getting two events in a given minute is about 7.6%, assuming I'm applying the distribution correctly.

I'm interested in the time distribution between groups of events: How long do I have to wait to see two events within a minute? What is the general form for this?

Comment: Call $(t_1,s_1)$ and $(t_2,s_2)$ the first intervals smaller than $1$ minute. Are you asking for the distribution of $s_2-s_1$?

Comment: Are you asking for how long to wait until you see one event and then another event within 1 minute after the first event?

Comment: Yes, both of those are better ways of stating the problem. In general, what is the distribution s_2 - s_1? Specifically, what is the mean of that distribution (how long to wait until I see one event then another event within a minute).

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution for this

Comment: Call $D=s_2-s_1$ and $X=t_2-s_1$. Conditioning on $X$, one sees that $D=X$ if $X<1$ and that $D=X+D'$ if $X>1$, where $D'$ is distributed like $D$ and independent of $D$. From here, the Laplace transform is $$E(e^{-xD})=\lambda\frac{1-e^{-\lambda-x}}{\lambda+x-\lambda e^{-\lambda-x}}.$$ Inverting this to recover the density requires more work but the mean is direct (differentiate the L transform at $x=0$).

Comment: One (probably) gets $$E(D)=\frac1{\lambda(1-e^{-\lambda})}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I have been following this Question for about a day now, and am
still not exactly sure what you are asking. Here are some
comments based on sequences of one-minute time intervals, for which the number of $X$ of events in one minute is Poisson with
mean 1/2.

EXACTLY ONE event in such an interval: $P(X = 1) =  0.3032653.$
Geometric mean waiting time for the first interval with exactly one event: reciprocal = 3.297443. By independence, given you have just seen such an interval, this is the waiting time for the next one.
Negative binomial mean waiting time for two such intervals:
double =  6.594885.

AT LEAST ONE event in such an interval: $P(X \ge 1) = 1 - P(X = 0)
= 0.3934693.$ Geometric mean waiting time for the first interval with
at least one event:  2.541494. Negative binomial mean waiting time for two
such intervals:  5.082988. Perhaps coincidentally, this is
the same as in the Comment where @Did speculates  $E(D) = 1/[\lambda(1-e^{-\lambda})] = 5.082988,$
for $\lambda = 1/2.$

AT LEAST TWO events in such an interval: $P(X \ge 2) = 0.09020401.$
Geometric mean waiting time for the first interval with at least two
events: 11.08598.